# AutoFill Large Number of Cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have 10,000 rows in my Google Sheet and I want the following sequence to repeat (**without using formula**):

```
        A          B
1      Q_1        R_1
2      Q_2        R_2
3      Q_3        R_3
.      .          .
.      .          .
10000  Q_10000    R_10000
```

I went through [THIS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75509?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) article, that suggests to select the 2 rows and drag the square at bottom-right, which is practically time consuming to drag it down to 10,000 rows.

How to do it without using formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Enter this formula in the first cell: `=CONCATENATE("Q_",ROW())`
- Select the first cell again.
- Type Ctrl+C to copy.
- Click in the address box (at the upper left corner of the sheet) and type in the range (e.g. `A1:A10000`) followed by Enter. This will select the range to be filled.
- Type Ctrl+V to paste formula into all selected cells and you're done.

Alternatively, if you have Excel, you may use `Home > Fill > Series...` menu to do this without using a formula.

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Comment: Thank you sir. Although I wanted to do it without using formula, as it happens in **Microsoft office 365** upon double clicking the square box at bottom-right. But, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible without a formula, but with something of a hack. Make sure your sheet has 10,000 rows. In A1 enter anything (`z` will do). Copy A1, select A2, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and Paste. Then in B1, `Q_1` and in B2 `Q_2`, select B1:B2 and *now* click the fill handle. Then `R_1` in C1, `R_2` in C2 and select etc.

Finally, delete ColumnA.

Answer (score 1):

Сomplementing the other answer.

You don’t need to add a fake column if you have data in the adjacent column. You can select C1 and C2, and double-click the fill handle.

[image]

From https://spreadsheetpoint.com/fill-down-google-sheets/:

> Pro Tip: When you have data in the adjacent column (left or right), you can also simply double click on the fill handle icon (instead of clicking and dragging). Double-clicking would do the same thing and fill down the column until the last filled cell in the adjacent column.

Comment: double-click, it's definitely amazing, I didn't know that before, thanks!